# Spark app console logs are not being logged to logfile

Tags: docker, apache-spark, logging, kubernetes, log4j

I am using the below log4j properties file for my spark cluster running on kubernetes. I still don't see the console logs being redirected to the `/var/log/SparkDriver.log`

I see driver/executor logs in the file but not the application output. For example, below gets logged to the pod logs instead of the file.

```
kubectl logs -f logtest2-1592207949203-driver -n sparkloads
...
2020-06-15 [info]: starting fluentd-1.9.2 pid=16 ruby="2.5.1"
2020-06-15 [info]: spawn command to main:  cmdline=["/opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/ruby", "-Eascii-8bit:ascii-8bit", "/usr/sbin/td-agent", "-d", "/var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid", "--under-supervisor"]
Pi is roughly 3.1421357106785535
```

I would like to see the last line in the `/var/log/SparkDriver.log` file.

What am I missing?

```
log4j.rootCategory=ALL,FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/var/log/SparkDriver.log
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

Adding my spark-submit command:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
 --deploy-mode cluster \
 --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
 --master k8s://https://spark.master.com \
 --conf spark.executor.instances=2 \
 --conf spark.app.name=logtest \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=myimage \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.docker.image.pullPolicy=Always \
 --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
 --conf spark.metrics.conf=/opt/spark/monitoring/metrics.properties \
 --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/spark/monitoring/log4j.properties"  \
 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/spark/monitoring/log4j.properties" \
 --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///opt/spark/monitoring/log4j.properties" \
 local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

Comment: Does your Dockerfile has the created path: /var/log/SparkDriver.log. Are you referring the logs on host machine or container? If you are referring to host machine, have you mounted the volume?

Comment: Yes, everything else (driver & executor logs) gets logged there except for the output of the job.

Comment: Kindly correct my inference, by "**there**" you mean everything(your Spark executor job logs) are getting logged in your **DOCKER** container under the log file: /var/log/SparkDriver.log? But your log statements inside code are not getting printed in Logfile? Is it possible for you to edit and elaborate your question?

Comment: I mean all logs including everything under `org.apache.spark` gets logged to the log file except the job output. `Pi is roughly 3.141855709278546` I did mention that in the question. I'm not sure what else can I add. Please let me know.

Comment: Thanks @deppfx. So I believe there are two possibilities, 1) Your are importing java.util.logging.Logger package in your code to log instead of **org.apache.log4j.Logger**, which prints to console and not to log file mentioned in log4j props. 2) If at all you're using **org.apache.log4j.Logger**, then in that case, somehow your log4j is being intercepted by a library in your classpath which redirects/converts to "java.util.logging".